# How to fix the error "Unfortunately closed myapp" in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app, i have a `listview`. If i click on one of the item in the list it will traverse to another intent which gives me to edit the values. It's not working for me for only one `listitem`. it will close the application. I checked the `logcat`. I saw it as `IndexOutOfBound` exception. Not able to fix it. Please help me.

```
lvDetail.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map = valuesList.get(position);

                DesigId = map.get(Desig_ID);
                DesigName = map.get(Desig);
                Desc1 = map.get(Desc);

                Intent in = new Intent(ViewAndUpdate.this, EnterDetails.class);
                in.putExtra("DesigId", "" + DesigId);
                in.putExtra("Desig", "" + DesigName);
                in.putExtra("Desc", "" + Desc1);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
```

This is the `logcat` part:

```
01-31 12:17:32.693: E/AndroidRuntime(2263): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 12:17:32.693: E/AndroidRuntime(2263): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 10
01-31 12:17:32.693: E/AndroidRuntime(2263):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-31 12:17:32.693: E/AndroidRuntime(2263):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
```

Comment: pls add your logcat and a part of your code about onItemClick

Comment: To avoid the exception put your code in `try-catch` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It said `size is 10` it means 0 to 9 but your position is 10 ! try `positon-1` instead of `position`

Comment: debug your app ! check  `valuesList` values and compare it`s indexes with your `position`

Comment: Yes there was some problem with the position. It's working fine now. Thank you.